# Volley POST return always empty params

Tags: php, postgresql, select, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a little problem: my request returns nothing.  I really don't know where the problem is.  I think it's a problem with syntax, but I don't know where.

```
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=killers_app;user=postgres;password=******;host=localhost;port=5432');

$req = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT user_password.password, user_search.search
    FROM user_search
    INNER JOIN user_password
    ON user_search.id = user_password.id
    WHERE user_search.search = ?");

$req->execute(array('flarize'));

$_COOKIE['search'] = $req['search'];
$_COOKIE['mdp'] = $req['password'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

Your error is that you haven't pulled any information from the query.  Try changing:

```
$req->execute(array('flarize'));

$_COOKIE['search'] = $req['search'];
$_COOKIE['mdp'] = $req['password'];
```

to...

```
$req->execute(array('flarize'));

$myResults = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$_COOKIE['search'] = $myResults['search'];
$_COOKIE['mdp'] = $myResults['password'];
```

There are multiple ways to "fetch" or return the results in PDO.  This was only the simplest solution that seemed to meet your needs.